# Calculate a sum of elements over a finite field $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I have this question for homework that I cannot solve.

> For $n\ge5$ prime number, calculate $1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

I tried proving it using induction but I can't get a good answer for $n=5$.
I also tried showing that the sum of the series above is equal to the sum of squares of the members of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field if and only if $n$ is a prime.

Comment: Is $n$ prime? It doesn't say so anywhere, but if it isn't, the reciprocals may not exist.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n$ is not a field when $n$ is not a prime number. But when $n$ is a prime number, and we interpret $\frac{1}{k^2}$ as the product $k^{-1}\cdot k^{-1}$, then we see that the sum is related to the sum of the quadratic residues in the field.

Comment: sorry, I fixed it. it's only regarding prime numbers

Comment: Did you manage to prove that the sum is the same as $1+2^2+3^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2$? That's the way I would go; then the sum of the squares can be calculated in the ordinary integers using the usual formula, and you can the reduce the result modulo $n$ afterwads.

Comment: I tried to do so but i get stuck here: $1+2^{-1}\cdot 2^{-1}+3^{-1}\cdot 3^{-1}+...+(n-1)^{-1}\cdot (n-1)^{-1}$ @HenningMakholm

Comment: Please read [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme's_theorem)

Answer (score 5):

Let $F=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ be a finite field of prime order $n$ and $a\ne 0$.
Then $k\mapsto ak$ is a permution of the nonzero elements of $F$. We conclude that 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{-2} =  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (ak)^{-2}=a^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{-2}.$$
Hence if we can find any $a\in F$ with $a\ne 0$ and $a^2\ne 1$, we immediately obtain
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^{-2}=0.$$
For $n\ge 5$, we can pick $a=2$.

Comment: A very elegant solution! +1

Answer (score 2):

First rewrite the sum as
$$ 1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2} = (\frac{1}{1})^2 + (\frac{1}{2})^2 + (\frac{1}{2})^2 + \cdots + (\frac{1}{n-1})^2 $$

Then note that the list of numbers you square,
$$ \frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n-1} $$
is just the list $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n-1$ in a different order. It must be so, because $x\mapsto \frac1x$ is a *bijection* from the set of nonzero elements in the field to itself. Since "$1,2,3,\ldots$" contains each of these elements once, their reciprocals must also contain each element exactly once.

Now, since addition is commutative, you can sum
$$ 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 $$
using the standard formula for sums of squares in the ordinary integers, and then reduce the result modulo $n$.